# Getting the column and row of an NSCell in an NSMatrix in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscell, nsmatrix

Given an NSMatrix and an NSCell is there a quick way to query the matrix to know at which row and column in the matrix the cell is placed. I would like to know this upon receiving action messages from NSActionCells.

The only way I can see of doing it is to loop through the rows and columns of the matrix and check for equality with the message sender, or give tags to the cells based on their position, which is ugly. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, isn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [ask the matrix which row and column a cell is at](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMatrix_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMatrix/getRow%3acolumn%3aofCell%3a).

Comment: Brilliant! I looked for a method that did that for ages but it somehow escaped my attention... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set a `-tag` value on the cells in question.  The canonical example of this is the cells in a matrix of digits for a calculator app.  Instead of trying to figure out where they are in the matrix, you can just check their tag to see what digit they represent.